# Django get information from AJAX and render template

Tags: django, ajax, datatable, render

i've a problem with Django when i try to render a template after getting information from AJAX in a datatable. Can you help me? Here is the code:

https://nopaste.xyz/?ccbe158548c85b5e#AxwFMud2UafGzzQVV3Gc7TKpzuo5UYxh6i7f675TRjDU

I read i cannot use render template after using request from AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

via ajax you can send data to back-end and also get a response (http or json response), then set the response as an innerHtml for an element.
in case you send data to back-end consider submit a form. then parse the form fields or its also possible to send data in json format and parse the json using python's json.
Django is base on python.